# 1px divider not fully placed within the container

Tags: css

I am trying to create a 1px divider between 4 sections in a single horizontal bar
Eg, A, B C and D. I have to keep a top padding = 10px and bottom padding=10 px between each of the section and the border of this horizontal bar. Also I need to keep a 1px vertical divider between A and B.
I am able to create top and bottom paddings of 10px and 1 px divider also. But the 1px line divider is not full, means its not touching from the top bar to bottom bar. Its placed only on the center where the text is placed. Can somebody please guide me how to extend the 1px divider to the entire length?

code snippet

```
<div class="top-bar">
        <div class="sub-section" >
            <p style="padding-left: 30px;">vvvvv</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-section">
            <p style="padding-left: 30px;">ysadfafdaafaf</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-section">
            <p style="padding-left: 30px;">werwtrwer rtyryryrytr</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-section">
            <p style="padding-left: 38px;">xsvcsfwr</p>
        </div>
    </div>



.top-bar{
width:800px;
float:left;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top:10px;

}
 .sub-section{
width:200px;
float:left;
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

}

Comment: If you could provide relevant HTML as well, I'm sure that could help us figure out a solution faster.

Comment: please place ur code in a fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your .sub-section class - this will place the border within the 200px width and will fix the layout problem you had. ( [More info about box-sizing property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9Zpg9/2/)**

```
.sub-section{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* add this */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Hi Danield, Thanks for ur solution..but its not working for me

Comment: Does the fiddle I posted work? If not - what's the problem with it?

Comment: Yes the fiddle is working for me..but when I use that in my code..its still the same..

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox has a vendor-specific rule for box-sizing. -  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; (Take a look at the css code in the fiddle - copy *both* rules into your project)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38708/discussion-between-user1049057-and-danield)